# Comparing GLMs with and without an interaction term

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction

So I had the base of a model that was based on my hypothesis:

Model 1

```r
lm(formula = mean_lookneg_reapp ~ ASRS_Total + 
    AHS_Total + CESD_Total + STAI_Total + AGE + 
    GENDER, data = em_rat_per_final)
```

In this case, CESD was significant while all other predictors were not.

Then I decided to add another variable in my exploratory analysis:

Model 2

```r
lm(formula = mean_lookneg_reapp ~ ASRS_Total + AHS_Total + 
    CESD_Total +
    **mean_conf_reapp** + STAI_Total + AGE + GENDER, 
    data = em_rat_per_final)
```

Here CESD was not significant and the new term mean_conf_reapp was very significant.
I ran an anova comparing the two and the second was a much better fit of the data. Thats all fair.

However, I then added an interaction between mean_conf_reapp and CESD to see:

Model 3

```r
lm(formula = mean_lookneg_reapp ~ ASRS_Total +
   AHS_Total + **CESD_Total * mean_conf_reapp** + 
   STAI_Total + AGE + GENDER, data = em_rat_per_final)
```

This model is even a better fit and the interaction term an mean_conf_reapp on its own are significant. I ran an anova comparing model 2 to model 3, and the F statistic was significant. So its a better fit than model 2?

My question is: I will write up that in my hypothesised model CESD was significant and that then as exploratory analysis I decided to add confidence rating and the interaction ... But is this a valid thing to do, or am I accidentally fishing for results?
Also, should I then control for multiple comparisons because I created three different models?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you explain clearly what you did, then it is OK.

A lot of people are not punctilious about this distinction between hypotheses and exploration. Good for you.